# php editing script doesn't work properly

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

The script is about editing data retrieved from database. It works fine (it edits the data) but the errors array is displayed immediately when the script runs. So i get all there errors: forgotten title, body, date.

For testing purposes i omit the title for example and click submit i get only the you forgot to enter your title

```
<?php 
$page_title = 'Edit a Joke';
include ('includes/header.html');
echo '<h1>Edit a Joke</h1>';

// Check for a valid Joke ID, through GET or POST:
if ( (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ) { // From view_jokes.php
$id = $_GET['id'];
} 
else { // No valid ID, kill the script.
echo '<p>This page has been accessed in error.</p>';

exit();
}

 require ('mysqli_connect.php'); 

 // Check if the form has been submitted:
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

$errors = array();
// Check for a title
if (empty($_GET['title'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter title.';
} else {
    $tit = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, ($_GET['title']));
    }
// Check for body:
if (empty($_GET['body'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter body.';
} else {
    $bod = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, ($_GET['body']));
}
// Check for date:
if (empty($_GET['date'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter date.';
} else {
    $dat = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, ($_GET['date']));
}
if (empty($errors))  // If everything's OK.
                {

        // Make the query:                            
        $q = "UPDATE joke SET title='$tit', body='$bod', date='$dat'  WHERE joke_id=$id LIMIT 1";
        $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { // If it ran OK.

            // Print a message:
            echo '<p>The joke has been edited.</p>';    

        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            echo '<p class>The joke could not be edited. Sorry</p>'; // Public message.

        }             
               }

                  else { // Report the errors.

    echo '<p>The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
    foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Print each error.
        echo " - $msg<br />\n";
    }
    echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p>';

    }// End of if (empty($errors)) IF.
    }// End of submit conditional.


   // Always show the form...

     // Retrieve the joke information:
  $q = "SELECT title, body, date  FROM joke WHERE joke_id=$id";     
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // Valid joke ID, show the form.

// Get the joke's information:
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM);

// Create the form:
echo '<form action="edit_joke.php" method="GET">

 <p> Title: <input type="text" name="title"  value="' . $row[0] . '" /></p>

<p> Body: <input type="text" style="height: 100" size="100" name="body" value="' . $row[1] . '" /> </p>

 <p> Date: <input type="date" name="date"  value="' . $row[2] . '"  /> </p>

  <p> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '" />
  </form>';

 } else { // Not a valid joke ID.
echo '<p>This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
  }

  mysqli_close($dbc);

  ?>
```

Comment: **A**: Wrap the executed code inside a conditional `isset()` using your submit button's named attribute.

Comment: I am confused on this issue because the question isn't formed properly. There are a lot of little things in the code I could point out but some might not help your issue. My first thought would be to look at `isset` vs `isempty`.  [Here is a handy gist attempting to explain](https://gist.github.com/juampy72/6029872)

Comment: Comments not being read I take it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i red it and tried to place isset(submit) but it didn't worked.. i didnt wanted to bother you. 

P.s i am new on this site. sorry

Comment: There's no bother, if something isn't clear, we ask questions ;)

Comment: I am sorry once again

Comment: Not a problem. It depends where the conditional is placed, however, do you really need the method to be GET? Using POST is safer if you don't "need" to use GET.

Comment: I am working on small project and i just deiced to go with GET all the time so i don't mess them.

Comment: If you don't "need" to use GET, don't. Use POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change at the beginning:

```
if (isset($_GET['test'])) {

    $errors = array();

   // Check for a title


   ....

}
   // Always show the form...
```

And add in your `<form`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="1">
```

Comment: nope it doesn't work... i still get the errors again

Comment: I see, test now with my new answer

Comment: IT WORKS! FINALLY !
can you please say few words what this does? 
As i see you are always passing a value to test so it is always set or?

Comment: Always set when you send the form, not when you come first.